# On the good usage of a pronoun

Tags: pronouns

A friend of mine (we are both non native english speakers, french actually) is writing lyrics and came to me to have an opinion on a sentence, and I actually am not 100% sure about the good answer.

The lyrics go like this :

> How could you convince the people?
>
> When you don't even believe in it

The question was about how we could refer to said people in the first sentence.
The three propositions are :

- Him
- It
- Them

I would totally rule out "Him" because people is plural here. "It" would refer to an object, so it only leaves "Them" available.

Would someone care to elaborate on this?

Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: I'm confused.  Where will you be using this pronoun?

Comment: I'm not really a hot shot in grammar, so maybe I'm using the wrong term, I'm sorry. 

Maybe I can rephrase as : How would you refer to "the people" from the first sentence, in the second sentence?

Comment: Normally you'd use "them".  Though in a lyric you have "poetic license".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pronoun you select must have an antecedent, i.e., a noun the pronoun refers to. Your readers (or listeners) will scan what they've read (or heard) to find a match suitable in number, gender, or person, or some combination.

*It* won't work because it's singular and neuter, which leaves out *people* and *you* respectively. You'll leave the audience wondering if the lyric shouldn't have been something like

> Of **altruism**, how could you convince the people
>   When you don't even believe in **it**?

*Him* is out since it's masculine, singular, and third person, conflicting with plural *people* and second-person *you*. If you persist, the audience will be wondering if they missed something like

> How could you think **John** could convince the people
>   When you don't even believe in **him**?

Just for fun and completeness, you can't have *you* be the antecedent unless you use a reflexive pronoun, since the believer and the believed in coincide:

> How could you convince the people
>   When **you** don't even believe in **yourself**?

*Them* does the trick, third person and plural; it's a match for the noun *people*.

Answer (score 0):

I think **them** works just fine:

> How could you convince **them**
>
> When you don't even believe in it

*Yourself* seems to be implied at the end of the second line.

Not clear you need *even* or *in*; depends on context. If we take them out:

> How could you convince **them**
>
> When you don't believe it

Reinserting *even*:

> How could you convince **them**
>
> When you don't even believe it

Not clear to whom **them** refers, but that's not necessarily  a problem for your lyrics. After all, these two lines have a larger context that only you and your friend know.

Comment: Oh, you got it wrong sir :)
I was not talking about replacing "people", but about how to refer to that subject in the second sentence.

Thank you though :)

Comment: @Shahor Your question certainly made it sound like you wanted to replace *people* with *them*. :-) Just trying to help. I did my best.

Comment: You're actually right, the phrasing is not perfect :)

Answer (score -2):

+If 'people' is the 'subject noun', You possibly wanted either: 'Those'(Distance) *or*'These'(Proximity), respectively.
     (a year later he sez as though it counts)

If i might say further, that given to be, appropriately it *were* in fact the intended diction of the lyric, 'Those/These people';  at pains, properly i should hold back on suggesting some, (shall we) 'concise', alternatives;

'That Lot', 'Them Lot', 'That Mob'. (*All* viable;)

My reasoning herewith, 'Those/These people', (it's all assuming the expression from in with which you are speaking, of course), some might consider 'cras' in  note. Also i suggest: I fear that *in translation*, there is too,a factor of risk, as coming across as sounding *a little*, Dago.

+Richard Kayser... 'believe in it' has more weight.. (it is a song lyric, Guy.. of course it wants weight..)

```
  (Note to self: Try not to be a year late next time)
```

Comment: This is ... hard to read, though it does seem to be addressing the question. Can we beg that you do some editing. Basically we're looking for expert answers, so we more or less expect answers to look like they were written by experts.